# Are instances of anonymous types serializable into a session?

Tags: c#, .net

**Problem**

I have a one time use object which is a composite of several objects and their properties. I would like to store this anonymous type into session and pull it back out again.

**Questions which need answering**

1. Is this a bad idea?  If so, is there is a better way? (without creating a serializable object and storing that in session)
2. Also wondering if this can be done?

Comment: And re "serializable"... "it depends" :) anon types are never `[Serializable]` nor `ISerializable`, so both `BinaryFormatter` and `XmlSerializer` will hate them... but ***if you absolutely had to*** they could be serialized with custom code. But writing a DTO is quicker, simpler and safer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it *is* a bad idea; anon types are a poor choice outside of a single location. There is something called "cast by example", but it is not good practice. The right approach is simply "write a simple class to represent that state". With auto-props that is trivial.

Dynamic is another viable option (that can talk to anon-types), but again: what are you tryig to save here? Write the POCO/DTO already... It doesn't even need to be Serializable in many cases (unless ou have an out-of-process state server; in which case it is ***more*** important to have a known DTO).

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to do the extra work. But i guess maintanablity is better then me typing less. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous types are intended to be used within a single method body.  Anytime you start passing them between methods you are asking for a bit of pain.  It's much simpler at that point to just go ahead and define a concrete type and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find a flexible middle ground between anonymous types and a traditional POCO, a [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) might work well for you.